# Веб-сервер через ADSL WiFi-роутер

Tags: wifi, роутер

У меня есть: socket server, WiFi adsl router, ADSL modem. Мне нужно чтобы все происходило так: любой пользователь в браузере прописал мой IP -> следовательно пошел запрос от модема к роутеру -> от роутера к компу. А как такое настроить, не знаю. Модем: TP-LINK WR340G. Выделенный IP провайдером это строка IP Adress:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой последовательности что стоит?Речь идет о локальном доступе или из инета?

Comment: Реч идет о интернет сервере.У меня ADSL модем подключен к ADSL WiFI routerУ (чтобы WiFI был по дому) а роутеру по WiFI каналу подключен ПК. Мне надо чтобы если кто то в интернете пропишет мой IP в браузере то Socket Server который стоит у меня на компе отвечал на запросы пользователей из интернета!

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая штука как проброс портов. Настраивается там где можно, в твоем случае в роутере.

**DMZ** DMZ Host IP Address: прописываем нужный адрес. Собственно твой IP внутренний от компа.

Ну и должен быть выделенный IP от провайдера иначе дело плохо.

**upd**

1. У провайдера берем Выделенный IP.(начинается никак не на 10. 10 - это внутренние адреса.) сразу, без просьбы пров IP не дает.
2. Прописываем в роутере новые настройки
3. прописываем проброс в DMZ + включаем этот самый DMZ в настройках
4. ребут роутера.
5. Пропуем подключиться по IP от провайдера.
6. Если не работает косяк в конечном компе, у которого сервис нужный не настроен.

> 10.64.93.78

Это не выделенный IP это внутренний IP. Если у тебя к модему идет витая пара, то вытащи её оттуда и вставь в роутер. Пороси прова дать нормальный IP, он кстати может попросить за это денег. от 100р в месяц до 100р в год.

Comment: Ща попробую!!! А это даст тот результат который мне нужен?

Comment: Нифига. Набираю адресс в браузере и получаю х.й в тарелке.

Comment: Народ если чем можете помогите ПЛС. А то я уже за..лся крутить роутер! Заранее СПС!

Comment: Ну так расскажи, IP есть выделенный или нет?

Comment: сфоткал экран меню роутера. помоему 10.64.93.78 это выделенный IP.http://cs301513.userapi.com/u58078118/-7/z_74fd63f7.jpg

Comment: Денис, а ты не со своего компа набирай-то, а с того, который во внешней сети.Речь шла о белом адресе, 10.x (192.168.x и 172.16.x-172.31.x) быть не может.Портфорвард нужно настроить на каждой железке, через которую пойдёт пакет.Как это у тебя wifi-adsl-роутер стоит за adsl-модемом? Ведь для роутера WAN - это adsl, то есть выход на телефон, а с модема идёт обычно витая пара (иногда usb). И почему не ограничиться одним только роутером, зачем ещё и модем? Ведь если роутер adsl, то в нём есть модем.

Comment: Я поражаюсь. >По-моему, по вашему ...Если так рассуждать то все президенты страны.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется. что в браузере если пропишут твой ип, не поможет, нужно скорей правильно сделать настройки сетевого соединения того пользователя чтобы он вышел в интернет, почему тебе нужно именно через твой компьютер. если у тебя есть роутер ( к нему и подключай все компьютеры которым нужен интернет), и зачем тебе WiFi adsl router и ADSL modem это одно и тоже?

Comment: > WiFi adsl router и ADSL modem это разные вещи!

Comment: Я знаю! У меня WiFI ADSL подключен к ADSL модему.

Comment: конечно нужно иметь белый адрес, а так твой компьютер стоит за таким же роутером как у тебя дома и раздает интернет, и к твоему компьтеру можно подклбчиться только через цпеыциальные программы, которые работаю через сервер в интернете' например teamviewer для подклбчения к другомву компьютеру через интернет. извинити если пишу глупость.